# Combining Rows in Javascript

Tags: javascript, merge, html-table, rows

I'm looking for some help on the Javascript angle of this problem.  I have a table that goes like...

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr> (Row 1)
   <td colspan="3">
    <p>This Says Something</p>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr> (Row 1a)
   <td>
    <select option>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr> (Row 2)
   <td colspan="3">
    <p>This Says Something</p>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr> (Row 2a)
   <td>
    <select option>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3">
    <p>This Says Something</p>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <select option>
   </td>
  </tr>
 <tbody>
</table>
```

There are actually more like 20 rows and row a's but I didn't think I'd want to copy them all.

I basically need to add a container row (a single row) around every two rows (# and #a).  Something like:

```
<tr> (Container Row 1)
 <td>
  +<tr> (Row 1)
  +<tr> (Row 1a)
 </td>
</tr>
```

It needs to cycle through the whole table.  Somehow it has to retain the HTML data inside since all of the "a"s have  options.

I hope this makes sense...

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm at a loss.  I'm novice at best at javascript and am struggling my way through the DOM and TOM methods.

Thank you so much in advance for any help or headway.

[EDIT] For clarification, the table is already constructed from a third party database, I am editing it after it's constructed. I guess this clarifies why it would have to be javascript to be done through the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Embed another table:

```
<tr> (Container Row 1)
 <td>
  <table>
    <tr><td>(Row 1a)</td></tr>
    <tr><td>(Row 1b)</td></tr>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Or if you are wanting to do that via Javascript, you can give the parent `<td>` an id and set it's innerHTML.

```
<tr> (Container Row 1)
 <td id='rowX'>
 </td>
</tr>


document.getElementById('rowX').innertHTML = "<table><tr><td>(Row 1a)</td></tr><tr><td>(Row 1b)</td></tr></table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950385/combining-rows-in-javascript/3950400#3950400) you can't add `tr` elements directly in `td` like you are trying.
You would first create an *inner table*.

If you were using jQuery you would do something like this:

```
//setup some click actions just to prove that they remain attached even after moving
$('#outterTable tr').click(function(){
    alert('You clicked on row: '+$(this).text());
});

//update the table (group each even row with the one after it)
$('#outterTable tr:even').each(function() {
    var $tr1 = $(this),
        $tr2 = $tr1.next('tr'),
        $t = $('<table></table>');
    $('<tr></tr>').append($t).insertBefore($tr1);
    //click actions will remain attached
    //if that is not required, than use $tr1.remove()
    $t.append($tr1).append($tr2);
});​
```

See this [live jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/danmana/sW3jJ/).

Comment: I know this will do what I need it to but I am unable to use jQuery because I am using a javascript include to editing a .asp (which I don't have access to to add jquery includes) page as it is constructed. Is there any way to translate this to regular javascript?  Or I saw this comment and was wondering what exactly it meant: "you could always prepend a minified verison to the source file."

Answer (score 0):

without jQuery it may look like that:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  function fx(table)
  {
    var tmp=document.createElement('table');
    tmp.appendChild(document.createElement('tbody'))

   while(table.rows.length)
   {
     if(table.rows.length%2==0)
     {
       var wrapper=tmp.lastChild.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
       wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
       wrapper.getElementsByTagName('TD')[0].appendChild(document.createElement('table'));
       wrapper.getElementsByTagName('TD')[0].lastChild.appendChild(document.createElement('tbody'));
     }
     wrapper.getElementsByTagName('TD')[0].lastChild.lastChild.appendChild(table.getElementsByTagName('TR')[0])
   }
   table.parentNode.replaceChild(tmp,table);
   tmp.setAttribute('border',1);
 }
  window.onload=function(){fx(document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0]);}
  //-->
  </script>
```

[Example@jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/Emg56/)

But: why do you need this grouping?
If the only benefit is a visible grouping I would prefer to do this by setting the borders  of the cells .
Give all cells a border and to the even a `border-top:none`  / to the odd a `border-bottom: none`

Comment: Thank you for this, I'll implement it as soon as I can to see if it works.  As for the reason for the grouping, each # row is a title and each #a row is the select option, but I have to apply a background image to each combined row set.